# Appium doesn't throw python exception, just fail with some JavaScript code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium

```
 frame_codeplug = None
    try:
        frame_codeplug = self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.NAME, 'FrameCodeplug')
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        pytest.fail(f'Expected element to be not None but it was None. Exception: {e}')

    assert frame_codeplug is not None, 'Expect element to be not None'
```

I can not catch that NoSuchElementException because
frame_codeplug = self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.NAME, 'FrameCodeplug')
is failing with such a message

```
        frame_codeplug = None
        try:
>           frame_codeplug = self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.NAME, 'FrameCodeplug')

test_standalone_read_write.py:41: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\venv\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py:409: in find_element
    return self.execute(RemoteCommand.FIND_ELEMENT, {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
..\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:345: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <appium.webdriver.errorhandler.MobileErrorHandler object at 0x00000292F40B6190>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page u...ode_modules\\\\appium\\\\node_modules\\\\@appium\\\\base-driver\\\\lib\\\\basedriver\\\\commands\\\\find.ts:75:12)"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """
        https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#errors
        """
        payload = response.get('value', '')
        try:
            payload_dict = json.loads(payload)
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
            return
        if not isinstance(payload_dict, dict):
            return
        value = payload_dict.get('value')
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            return
        error = value.get('error')
        if not error:
            return
    
        message = value.get('message', error)
        stacktrace = value.get('stacktrace', '')
        # In theory, we should also be checking HTTP status codes.
        # Java client, for example, prints a warning if the actual `error`
        # value does not match to the response's HTTP status code.
        exception_class: Type[sel_exceptions.WebDriverException] = ERROR_TO_EXC_MAPPING.get(
            error, sel_exceptions.WebDriverException
        )
        if exception_class is sel_exceptions.WebDriverException and message:
            if message == 'No such context found.':
                exception_class = appium_exceptions.NoSuchContextException
            elif message == 'That command could not be executed in the current context.':
                exception_class = appium_exceptions.InvalidSwitchToTargetException
    
        if exception_class is sel_exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            raise sel_exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException(
                msg=message,
                stacktrace=format_stacktrace(stacktrace),
                alert_text=value.get('data'),
            )
>       raise exception_class(msg=message, stacktrace=format_stacktrace(stacktrace))
E       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
E       Stacktrace:
E       NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
E           at errorFromW3CJsonCode (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:1040:25)
E           at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:909:14)
E           at WADProxy.command (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:353:19)
E           at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
E           at WinAppDriver.sendCommand (C:\Users\FTMW63\.appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\lib\winappdriver.js:230:12)
E           at WindowsDriver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\FTMW63\.appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\lib\commands\find.js:11:10)
E           at WindowsDriver.findElOrElsWithProcessing (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:60:12)
E           at WindowsDriver.findElement (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:75:12)

..\venv\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py:122: NoSuchElementException

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

self = <StandaloneReadWrite.test_standalone_read_write.TestStandaloneRead object at 0x00000292F3C5DA50>

    def test_read_radio(self):
        self.open_app()
        self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, 'ButtonReadRadio').click()
        self.window2_desired_caps = {
            "platformName": "windows",
            "appium:deviceName": "WindowsPC",
            "appium:automationName": "Windows",
            "app": 'Root'
        }
        self.windriver = webdriver.Remote(self.appium_url, self.window2_desired_caps)
        time.sleep(5)
        result = self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, 'ProgText').text
        time.sleep(15)
        frame_codeplug = None
        try:
            frame_codeplug = self.windriver.find_element(AppiumBy.NAME, 'FrameCodeplug')
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
>           pytest.fail(f'Expected element to be not None but it was None. Exception: {e}')
E           Failed: Expected element to be not None but it was None. Exception: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
E           Stacktrace:
E           NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
E               at errorFromW3CJsonCode (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:1040:25)
E               at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:909:14)
E               at WADProxy.command (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:353:19)
E               at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
E               at WinAppDriver.sendCommand (C:\Users\FTMW63\.appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\lib\winappdriver.js:230:12)
E               at WindowsDriver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\FTMW63\.appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\lib\commands\find.js:11:10)
E               at WindowsDriver.findElOrElsWithProcessing (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:60:12)
E               at WindowsDriver.findElement (C:\Users\FTMW63\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:75:12)
```

Why am I getting these JavaScript-like exceptions here? In other tests I can catch NoSuchElementException but here it doesn't work.

I'm using Python 3.11.4, Appium 2.1.0 with Windows Application Driver.